# Update the viewController from the controller in MVC with SWIFT

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, delegates, protocols

I'm creating an app with swift. The app get weather from openweathermap.com api in the class WeatherDataModel then when the data are loaded, the model ask the viewController to update the datas

I'm on Xcode 10.2.1 with swift 5

I've create a protocol called in the model to update the data but the updateDisplayDelegate?.updateWeatherDataOnDisplay() is always nil and even if I get the data from the JSON in the console it won't update on the screen

```swift
class WeatherDataModel {

  var updateDisplayDelegate: ProtocolUpdateDisplay?

  func updateWeaterData(json : JSON) {
    updateDisplayDelegate?.updateWeatherDataOnDisplay()
  }
}

public protocol ProtocolUpdateDisplay {
    func updateWeatherDataOnDisplay()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  let weatherDataModel = WeatherDataModel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     weatherDataModel.updateDisplayDelegate = self
  }

extension MainViewController: ProtocolUpdateDisplay {

    func updateWeatherDataOnDisplay() {
        cityLabel.text = weatherDataModel.city
        tempLabel.text = weatherDataModel.temperature
        weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: weatherDataModel.weatherIconName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `delegation` pattern for model. Consider using notification:

```
func updateWeaterData(json : JSON) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: Notification.Name("WeatherDidUpdate")))
}
```

and observe in any controller you want to respond to this notification:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateWeatherDataOnDisplay(_:)), name: Notification.Name("WeatherDidUpdate"), object: nil)
}

@objc func updateWeatherDataOnDisplay(_ notification: Notification) {
    cityLabel.text = weatherDataModel.city
    tempLabel.text = weatherDataModel.temperature
    weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: weatherDataModel.weatherIconName)
}
```

and remove observer at last:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with you're methode where should I put the deinit then?

Comment: Right at the view controller.

Comment: Thank you, with the notification it partially worked, the UI update but before the data are loaded from the API request

Comment: actually it is not that, after making some print, the notification work well, but if I print my parameters in the model, the data are updated from the JSON, but if I print it from the viewController print(weatherDataModel.city) the data is the initialisation value... any idea?

Comment: Sorry in the code I provided, I'm accidentally `post` a notification inside the view didLoad. Updated.
no just call `updateWeaterData` after the server respond.